# Как правильно сделать плавную анимацию стрелки?

Tags: css, jquery, transition

Как сделать чтобы стрелка после наведения еще немного обратно шла? [пример тут](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/SUq3XpLGUjm15Q)
Или может есть какой-нибудь онлайн генератор? подобных ненашел

```css
    svg {
        width:50px;
  
    }
    .cases-link svg {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0.9, 0.265, 2);
      /* transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 5); */
    }

    .cases-link:hover svg {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
  <a href="#" id="cases" class="cases-link">
        <svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 126 126">
          <defs>
            <style>
              .b {
                fill: #000;
              }
            </style>
          </defs>
          <polygon class="b" points="112.65 -.17 0 -.17 0 13.52 103.67 13.52 .65 116.53 10.29 126.17 112.65 23.85 112.65 126.12 126.29 126.12 126.29 13.52 126.29 -.17 112.65 -.17"></polygon>
        </svg>
      </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить `translation` на `:hover` время маленькое а на сам `svg` без `hover` уже увеличить параметр времени

```css
svg {
        width:50px;
  
    }
    .cases-link svg {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      transition: transform .9s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0.9, 0.265, 2);
      /* transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 5); */
    }

    .cases-link:hover svg {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0.9, 0.265, 2);
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="cases" class="cases-link">
        <svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 126 126">
          <defs>
            <style>
              .b {
                fill: #000;
              }
            </style>
          </defs>
          <polygon class="b" points="112.65 -.17 0 -.17 0 13.52 103.67 13.52 .65 116.53 10.29 126.17 112.65 23.85 112.65 126.12 126.29 126.12 126.29 13.52 126.29 -.17 112.65 -.17"></polygon>
        </svg>
      </a>
```